# How to set values of billing info and shipping info in custom email templates?

Tags: magento2, email-templates

This is my `email_template.html`

```
 <table class="order-details">
                <tr>
                    <td class="address-details">
                        <h3>{{trans "Billing Info"}}</h3>
                        <p>{{var  formattedBillingAddress|raw}}</p>
                    </td>
                     {{depend order.getIsNotVirtual()}}
                    <td class="address-details">
                        <h3>{{trans "Shipping Info"}}</h3>
                        <p>{{var formattedShippingAddress|raw}}</p>
                    </td>
                    {{/depend}}
                </tr>
</table>
```

and in my observer

```
$templateVars = array(
            'store' => $this->storeManager->getStore(),
            'message'   => 'We processed your order ID We will contact you soon in mail for the acknowledgement if you not receive mail within 4 hours please get help from support@xxx.com',
            'order' => $order,
            'store'=> $store,
            'productName'=> $productName
       );

->setTemplateVars($templateVars)
```

My question is how can i set values of billing info, shipping info and payment method in this email template.

Comment: Which is event you catch?

Comment: checkout_onepage_controller_success_action

Comment: @Ramkishan  you ask how to pass/set value in email templates? or how to get values in observer?

Comment: @Ramkishan,
My observer file has code like below,
$transport = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder');
$templateVars = array(
    'myvar1' => 'testing data'
   );
$transport->setTemplateVars($templateVars);



But could't retrive this value in my Email...
In Email template , {{var myvar1}}

Comment: You should ask a new question @Vigna. beacuase in comments i can't explain you whole thing.

Comment: @Ramkishan, I posted a new question , http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/162497/how-to-set-custom-value-in-default-email-template-magento-2

Comment: sorry @vigna I am busy right now but i will definitely give your answer later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject class Renderer used for formatting an order address and some classes for Payment into your constructor.

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Renderer
 */
protected $addressRenderer;

 /**
 * @var \Magento\Payment\Helper\PaymentHelper
 */
protected $paymentHelper;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Renderer $addressRenderer,
    \Magento\Payment\Helper\PaymentHelper $paymentHelper
) {
    $this->addressRenderer = $addressRenderer;
    $this->paymentHelper = $paymentHelper;
}
```

Add to `$templateVars`:

```
$templateVars = array(
        'store' => $this->storeManager->getStore(),
        'message'   => 'We processed your order ID We will contact you soon in mail for the acknowledgement if you not receive mail within 4 hours please get help from support@xxx.com',
        'order' => $order,
        'store'=> $store,
        'productName'=> $productName,
        'payment_html' => $this->getPaymentHtml($order),
        'formattedShippingAddress' => $this->getFormattedShippingAddress($order),
        'formattedBillingAddress' => $this->getFormattedBillingAddress($order),
   );
```

Build the methodes for shippping , billing address and payment:

```
/**
 * @param Order $order
 * @return string|null
 */
protected function getFormattedShippingAddress($order)
{
    return $order->getIsVirtual()
        ? null
        : $this->addressRenderer->format($order->getShippingAddress(), 'html');
}

/**
 * @param Order $order
 * @return string|null
 */
protected function getFormattedBillingAddress($order)
{
    return $this->addressRenderer->format($order->getBillingAddress(), 'html');
}

/**
 * Get payment info block as html
 *
 * @param Order $order
 * @return string
 */
protected function getPaymentHtml(Order $order)
{
    return $this->paymentHelper->getInfoBlockHtml(
        $order->getPayment(),
        $this->identityContainer->getStore()->getStoreId()
    );
}
```

See a good sample here:

`vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Email/Sender/OrderSender.php`
`vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/email/order_new.html`

Comment: Thank you @Khoa i got the values. your post was very helpful.

Comment: @Khoa TruongDinh,
My observer file has code like below,
$transport = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder');
$templateVars = array(
    'myvar1' => 'testing data'
   );
$transport->setTemplateVars($templateVars);



But could't retrive this value in my Email...
In Email template , {{var myvar1}}

Answer (score 0):

```
$templateVars = array(
        'store' => $this->storeManager->getStore(),
        'message'   => 'We processed your order ID We will contact you soon in mail for the acknowledgement if you not receive mail within 4 hours please get help from support@xxx.com',
        'order' => $order,
        'store'=> $store,
        'productName'=> $productName
   );
```

you can use the above variable in email templates like

for write static text you can use -> {{trans "Dear"}}

for include variable you can use -> {{var productName}}

for example you greet your customer in mail templates like

```
<h1 style="font-size:22px;font-weight:normal;line-height:22px;margin:0 0 11px 0;">{{trans "Dear "}} {{var customer_name}},</h1>
```

In this above example customer name is the $templateVars array index. You need to get customer name from observer after that you can pass that value into $templateVars array.

Comment: i need to print billing info and shipping info in my templates. how can i do this ?

Comment: do you get that values in observer? pls show your full observer code

Answer (score 0):

For magento 2.3, replace this

```
\Magento\Payment\Helper\PaymentHelper $paymentHelper
```

with

```
\Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentHelper
```