# How to set custom value in default Email template Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I declared a custom variable to New customer Email template,

```
{{var myvar1}}
```

I am assigning the value to that variable from my observer,

```
    <?php
    namespace test\test\Observer;

    use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

    class Customersubmit implements ObserverInterface
    {
        public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
        {
            $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
            $customerId = $customer->getId();
            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $transport = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\Tran‌​sportBuilder');  

            if($customerId){
                $templateVars = array( 'myvar1' =>  'testing data' ); 
                $transport->setTemplateVars($templateVars); 
            }       
        }
    }
```

But I couldn't retrieve this value in my email . Could anyone say where I am wrong

Comment: Take a look this if it helps you   http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/136475/how-to-set-values-in-custom-email-templates/162508#162508

Comment: Ok, even I tried in same way but it does'nt work for me

Comment: which event you are using ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass array as `DataObject()`

```
$transport = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\Tran‌​sportBuilder');
$postObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(array( 'myvar1' =>  'testing data' )); 
$transport->setTemplateVars(['customvar' => $postObject]);
```

In template file,

```
{{var customvar.myvar1}}
```

Comment: even after passing array as DataObject(), I couldn't retrieve the value.

Comment: try with above code.

Comment: I have tried,it dosen't helps. even I can't save the customer

Answer (score 0):

Put the variable which you want to set in Array first like :

```
$emailTempVar = array('name' => $cx_name,'email' => $cx_email);
```

then access it using :

```
$this->transportBuilder->setTemplateVars([
                        'email' => $emailTempVar['email'],
                        'name' => $emailTempVar['name']
                    ])
```

Then you can use it in email template like:

{{var name}} /{{var email}}

It works for me!

Comment: No , it's not working. I tried. Even I can't save the customer

Comment: can you paste your observer's code here?

Comment: I have pasted my observer